# How to insert a base64 string into database without errors?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, base64

I need to insert a base64 string into my sql server database. It ends in an equals sign "=" and I can't seem to do it without getting an `"incorrect syntax near '='" error`. Also, if the string begins with a number (say, `"1aBgrfe="`), then I get an error "incorrect syntax near 'aBgrfe='". The data type for the column is `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. The sql insert statement in my c# program is

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES ('" + myBase64String + '")
```

I understand that I may have to write a stored procedure, which I've never done before.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If your code actually looked like that, then you would get a syntax error when you compiled it. You have the `'` and the `"` in the wrong order after the string variable.

Comment: An extract of your code could be useful to understand the scenario that raise this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a parameterized query, not a string concatenation

```
string cmdText = "INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (@str)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connection);
connection.Open();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@str", myBase64String);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Of course you need to specify the column names if you have other columns in that table

```
string cmdText = "INSERT INTO MYTABLE (colForbase64string) VALUES (@str)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Convert() method in sql. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

```
"INSERT INTO MYTABLE (YourColumnName) VALUES(NVARCHAR(MAX), '" + myBase64String + "')";
```